# Derivative of zeta at positive even integers

Tags: riemann-zeta-function, zeta-functions

Is there a general formula that sums up all values of $ζ′(2n)$, such that $n\in\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Other than $-2 \sum_{n=2}^\infty (\log n)n^{-2}/ (1 -n^{-2})^2$?

Comment: Yes. I want close form.

Comment: Well, it is a real constant completely determined by its definition. But so are $\pi$ and $e$, so what will change if we find some fancy relation between them? Of course, if it were rational, that would make some difference, but I don't think that this will be proved any time soon and I would rather bet that the number is transcendental. In other words, *what exactly are you intending to do with that closed form that cannot be done with the series representation*?

Comment: I think the general expectation is that there is _no_ such "closed form" ... unless we perhaps allow considerably more exotic notions of "closed form", akin to conjectural things about $\zeta(\mathrm{odd})$ (aiming in a different direction than Apery, et al).

Comment: @fedja Finding closed form expressions for infinite sums is a pretty crucial thing to want to do.  You might just have simply asked the OP the motivation for the problem.

Comment: @JesseElliott And that is exactly what I did (see the italicized text) because I'm ready to bet 100 against 1 that the problem is intractable as posed but if what the OP is after is something specific (like computing that number with high precision reasonably fast, say), then there are tools that do not require expressing it as a combination of famous constants, so, perhaps, something useful can be done without answering the question as posed.

Answer (score 6):

Partial answer: in my book Springer Graduate Texts in Math 240 page 142
Exercise 92, I give six equivalent formulas for the very similar sum $\sum_{n\ge2}\zeta'(n)$. I suggest first that you prove the equivalence of the six,
and second that you adapt this proof to your sum, which should probably
also give you six equivalent formulas.

Comment: Totally off topic, but that's a wonderful book that I found very useful to me both in learning number theory and learning to love number theory.

Comment: Just for completeness, the title of the book is "Number Theory: Volume II: Analytic and Modern Tools".